# Caanimation "position" breakes Autoresizing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-animation, core-graphics

I have a problem with CAAnimation and AutoresizingMask. A have a view with autoresizingMask

```
contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

When I rotate device, it's allways on the center of it's parentView.
But if i apply some CoreAnimation to it's position, it's stop autoresize. If I animate another properties(alpha or scale) autorotation works well.

What's wrong with "position"-key animation?

Comment: What behavior are you expecting during position animations? Flexible margins on all sides only causes the view to stay centered if it already is centered.

Comment: When I'm create contentView - I set it in center of it's parentView. And after that I want to show it with some animation. If I use fade animation - it's autoresize normal, but if I show it with move animation(from the top of screen to center) - then it's autoresizing breakes.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist I found. Problem was in contentAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;